# DevOps doesn't show all matching stories/tasks when searching

Tags: azure-devops

I can start typing "#per" in a Devops task description/comment and it brings up suggestions. However it only shows a subset of all the stories which means the one I want is rarely listed and I have to go look it up.

For instance I have two work items (on the same epic) called "perform analysis" and "determine permutations" but typing "#per" only shows the second one.

Is there some logic used in the searching based on item fields that could be to blame i.e. it's a feature rather than just not working well?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, when using the **`#mentioned`** to link work items, the expected syntax is **`#{ID}`** instead of **`#{Keyword}`**.

If using the syntax **`#{Keyword}`**, it may be not able to return the expected result. So, it is recommended using the **`#{ID}`** as possible to search and link work items.

For more information, you can reference "[**Link work items**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/add-link?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser)".

**[UPDATE]**

When you use **#{ID}** to search and link a work item, normally it will prioritize the work items that you've recently modified or are assigned to you.

Comment: A search that only lets you search a numerical id isn't very good. Also in my case, items matching my id don't turn up either e.g. I type "#123" and 12345 is not suggested but 41235 is. It seems a more general issue that some items are just not being included in the search. Whether that's because of some details on the WI or a bug is the question :)

Comment: Hi @Mr.Boy, I have updated my above answer with more explanations. Please check it. And I agree the current way may be not perfect enough. Thanks for your feedback.